# jQuery selector for selecting an input field with a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
<input type="text" class="required" value="XXX" name="abc">
<input type="hidden" class="required" value="XXX" name="abcd">
<input type="text" class="required" value="XXX" name="abcef">
```

i have many input fields like this.

i need a jQuery selector where i can select a text field whose class is required

right now to select textfield i use $(':input[type="text"]')

how do i also put a condition to select class="required."

**EDIT**

so say now i have the following input fields

```
<div id="validate_info">
<input type="text" class="required" value="XXX" name="abc">
<input type="hidden" class="required" value="XXX" name="abcd">
<input type="text" class="required" value="XXX" name="abcef">
<input type="password" class="required" value="XXX" name="abcefg">
<input type="text"  value="XXX" name="abcefgsa">
<input type="password" value="XXX" name="abcsaefg">
</div>
```

i need one selector that can select all type="text", type="password" which has class="required"
i tried

```
$('#validate_info $("input.required").filter("[type="password"],[type="text"]")');
```

but this doesnt seem to work.

Comment: `$("input.required").filter("[type="password"],[type="text"]")` is not a selector string.  It should be `$("#validate_info input.required").filter("[type='password'],[type='text']")` or `$("input.required", "#validate_info").filter("[type='password'],[type='"text']")`.  Also, make sure you use the right quotes inside quotes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$(':input.required[type="text"]')
```

EDIT:

This will be slightly faster:

```
$('input.required[type="text"]')
```

Note:

`:input` will get all form elements (`<select>`, `<textarea>`, etc.)

`input` will only get `<input>` elements, and is slightly faster.

Comment: +1 - This is probably the fastest selector of all the answers.

Comment: Better if you use `input` instead of `:input`. Then jQuery can use browser methods.

Comment: now if i have another field of type password and i also need a selector for that how do i do that?

Comment: @Kishore: `$(':input.required[type="password"]')`, or whatever combination of selectors you want.

Comment: i need type = password and type =text in the same selector something like $(':input.required[type="password"][type="text"]') whose class should be required how ca this be done?

Comment: @Kishore: You have to use the multiple selector then: `$('input.required[type="password"], input.required[type="password"]')` or filter: `$('input.required').filter('[type="password"],[type="password"]')`

Comment: i have tried but this doesnt seem to work i have edited my question can you please look at it

Comment: @Kishore: `$("#validate_info input.required").filter("[type='password'],[type='text']")`

Answer (score 8):

```
$('.required:input[type="text"]')
```

(also `$('input.required[type="text"]')`)

Answer (score 7):

```
$(':input[type="text"][class="required"]')
```

That should work

http://jsfiddle.net/ck8wt/

#### Edit

lol ... I couldn't see the forest through the trees. :P  I'll leave mine up too though just as an illustration of how many ways this can be done. XD

Answer (score 4):

If you just add the class to your selector, it should do what you are looking for.

```
$('.required:input[type="text"]')
```