# Object has no method 'charAt' in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am attempting to use the [autoNumeric jQuery plug-in](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) which helps with the conversion of various currencies in jQuery.

The plug-in itself works when I use it in a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Bp7Mw/).

```
$(function () {
    $('.money').autoNumeric('init', {
        aSign: '$',
        vMin: '-999999999.99',
        nBracket: '(,)'
    });
});
```

However, as soon as I integrate it into a big, legacy project, I start receiving the above error on line 194. I know why I'm getting the error - a string is not being passed into the negativeBracket function (`negativeBracket(s, nBracket, oEvent)` is the signature). Instead, it seems to be a jQuery object - e.fn.init[1](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/). I'm confused on how this might be happening. I realize the community may not be able to give a direct answer, but I would love (and will accept as an answer) being pointed in the right direction as nothing has jumped out at me so far.

**Update**

So, have some additional info that may be of help. It still has me stumped how it's happening (unfortunately, the answers below didn't help to provide any additional insight). When I link in autoNumeric, I key it off of any text field with the class money. *It does work as I am typing in the box. I can see see formatting.* However, when I tab into a new box, the box I just finished typing in clears itself completely after hitting line 152 in autoNumeric with the same exact error.

@Carlos487 was correct in his answer when he said I have an object that is not a string. I instead have an object that, I believe, is a function. Here's what I'm seeing in Chrome debugger tools:

```
e.fn.init[1]

> 0: input#price.money required
> context: input#price.money required
 length: 1
 selector: ""
> __proto__: Object[0]
```

The "arrowed" items can be further expanded out. I don't know if this provides any more clues, but it's at least something a bit different.

Comment: Looks like a typo. Check the source of the plugin, it needs to be `charAt`.

Comment: @Bergi - That was my own typo...should be charAt. Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issue was a myriad of issue compounding into the error I saw. A couple things that was happening:

1. The validator plug-in was wrapping the jQuery object in its own structure (hence the charAt issue).
2. Once I fixed that, I also learned that some homegrown code was also wiping and rewriting data into the field to provide formatting (which is what autoNumeric is also doing), so autoNumeric would bomb out because it would get a null value and attempt to format it.

There was some other random craziness that also needed cleaned up. So...issue resolved! Still more to work on, but at least this hurdle is past. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The errors like

> no method XXXXX in Object

are produced because you are trying to call **obj.XXXX()** and obj is not of the desired type, in your particular case a **string**.

Have you tried in another browser because older or IE can be a little troublesome. I would recomend using chrome developer tools with your legacy app to see if anything else is conflicting or producing the error

Comment: I have actually been having this problem in Chrome (as well as every other browser). However, you are right - the plugin is receiving an array with a single item (the input field) rather than the text from the input field. I can't be sure, but it looks like there is some "wrapping" magic happening in which the object is being wrapped up in something else earlier on. Unfortunately, I just got this code base, and I am having trouble tracing to see if my hunch is correct. (And...no clue how I'd fix it!) Thanks for the thought.

Comment: That could happen if you are using a UI library like jQuery UI, that kind of libraries tend to transform and wrap objects in markup. You should try to refine your selector to get input with class Ex: $('input.money') or like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984926/jquery-selector-for-selecting-an-input-field-with-a-class

Also be aware that if any other kind of element uses the class **money** and it's not supported by the plugin should throw an error  and break all the javascript from the page

Answer (score 0):

I will bet money that you are using a second library which is interfering with jQuery. It has probably overridden `$` with its own function.

Try using `jQuery` instead of `$`:

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('.money').autoNumeric('init', {
        aSign: '$',
        vMin: '-999999999.99',
        nBracket: '(,)'
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah...I did try this. Unfortunately, I still have the same problem per my expanded information shown above. Don't know if that provides anything additional information that may help. I am completely stumped. Thank you for your help so far.